# How to prevent format change with replace

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro that calculates some formulas,  that are stored as text at first in one column, by replacing some codes by their associated int values and later print the result in the desired column.
e.g. `dAGR99001/dAGR99002` is replaced by 2/2 since their values for certain month/year are both 2,  later this text formula converted into a proper formula by adding the equal sign at the beginning and prints the result of it in another column.

My problem is that when replacing the codes by their associated int values, Excel automatically converts it to a date. For example on the above formula, it should be replaced by 2/2 but instead, it's returning 2/Feb (2/Fev in Portuguese) as in 2/2/2019 and when later calculating it the final result is 43498 (days since 1/1/1900). 
How can I prevent this from happening?

[image: Before running the macro] → [image: After running the macro]

Note that both the column where the text formula is and the associated int values of the codes are stored has General format. I also tried to save them as Number or Text but the problem still persisted. 
This is my code

```
Sub Looper()

Dim x As Integer

    For x = 10 To 60
        getformulas x
    Next x

End Sub
Sub getformulas(MonthNum As Integer)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsLookup As Worksheet
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet
    Dim aLookup() As Variant
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim lCodesLookupCol As Long
    Dim lCodesConvertCol As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lrow As Long

Call OptimizeCode_Begin

    With Sheets("Variaveis")
        lrow = .Range("A:BA").Find(What:="", after:=.Range("A2"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("Indicadores")
    Set wsLookup = wb.Worksheets("Variaveis")
    Set wsPaste = wb.Worksheets("Formulas")

    aLookup = wsLookup.Range("A2:BA" & lrow) '("A2:AO441")

    lCodesLookupCol = LBound(aLookup, 2)
    lCodesConvertCol = UBound(aLookup, 2)  

    With wsData.Range("H2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))

            For i = 1 To UBound(aLookup, 1)
                .Replace aLookup(i, lCodesLookupCol), aLookup(i, MonthNum - 4), xlPart, , False
            Next i

            If .Cells.Count = 1 Then
                ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
                aData(1, 1) = .Formula
            Else
                aData = .Formula
            End If

            For i = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
                If Len(aData(i, 1)) > 0 And Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then aData(i, 1) = "=" & aData(i, 1)
                wsData.Cells(i + 1, MonthNum) = aData(i, 1)
                If Left(aData(i, 1), 1) <> "=" Then
                    wsData.Cells(i + 1, MonthNum).Value = "Error"
                End If
                On Error Resume Next
            Next i

        End If

Call OptimizeCode_End
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True

    End With

    Worksheets("Formulas").Range("B2:B228").Copy
    Worksheets("Indicadores").Range("H2:H228").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
    Application.Goto Worksheets("Indicadores").Cells(2, 6)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just add the `'` beforehand when writing to the cell?

Comment: In Excel, if you place an apostrophe in front of the cell entry it interprets it as text. Did you try that?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just dumb. Manually it didn't work but I found a way of inserting it into the macro and it worked. Thanks, guys.